# Primitive types in Reflection API

Tags: java, reflection

Whenever I tried to use primitive type like `boolean` with `Class.forName()` syntax and with `getClass()`, compile time error was generated, but when I used `.class` syntax, it worked and the output was `boolean`.

My question is why does it work with `.class` syntax? I thought there should be always an object in place of `String` in `String.class`.

```
public class reflect2 
{
     public static void main(String[] args) 
     {      
          Class c1 = boolean.class;     
          System.out.println(c1.getName());     
    }
}
```

Comment: "*reflection API can be applied only on objects*" - is a wrong sentence. APIs is not applied on objects.

Comment: boolean.class compiles as Boolean.TYPE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`getClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) is a method defined in `java.lang.Object`, and methods can only be called on instances.

The `.class` is part of the *class literal*, it is not a method call, and it is allowed on primitive types too.

Quoting from the [**The Java™ Language Specification Section 15.8.2. Class Literals**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8.2):

> A *class literal* is an expression consisting of the name of a class, interface, array, or **primitive type**, or the pseudo-type `void`, followed by a `'.'` and the token `class`.

And finally qutoing from the javadoc of [`Class.forName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName-java.lang.String-):

> Returns the Class object associated with the **class** or **interface** with the given string name.

So `Class.forName()` only works for classes and interfaces and **not** for primitive types.

Answer (score 3):

This is mentioned in the [Oracle Java tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/class/classNew.html) :

> **The .class Syntax**
>
> If the type is available but there is no instance then it is possible
> to obtain a Class by appending ".class" to the name of the type. **This
> is also the easiest way to obtain the Class for a primitive type.**
>
> boolean b; 
> Class c = b.getClass();   // compile-time error
> Class c = boolean.class;  // correct
>
> Note that the statement boolean.getClass() would produce a compile-time error because a boolean is a primitive type and cannot be dereferenced. **The .class syntax returns the Class corresponding to the type boolean**.

You need to be able to represent the type of primitives somehow, since it is required when, for example, you use reflection to search for methods or constructors that have primitive argument types.

Comment: is boolean.class replaced by Boolean.class.

Comment: @Aamir No, `boolean.class` is not the same as `Boolean.class` and if you write `boolean.class` it is not automatically replaced by `Boolean.class`.